# How can I get a list of execution times for my Sitecore scheduled task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task in Sitecore and I want to find the timestamp for its past executions. I can find this information in the Sitecore logs by looking to see when the info message gets written like:

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 03:31:12 INFO Starting: <TaskName> (asynchronously)
ManagedPoolThread #18 03:31:12 INFO Job started: ScheduleCommand '{<ID>}'
ManagedPoolThread #3 03:31:13 INFO Ended: <TaskName>
```

This works in a sense but it is pretty tedious analyzing logs like this.
Is this history stored in a database/table anywhere that I can query?

Comment: I know for publishing you can get the last published timestamp. Maybe having log in the schedule job can help or insert a timestamp in a custom database which you can query easily

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the [Sitecore Log Analyzer](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx). You can filter by timeframe and add a string qualifier and look for Job started/ended statements in the logs.

[image]

Comment: Are these values also stored in the database?