# Get last time job ran date/time

Tags: logging, scheduled-tasks

I have a very basic question and only because I haven't been able to find any reference or source for it.

In Sitecore, how can I **programmatically** get the last run date/time of a job that is configured in the web.config or another config file? I had opened another question like this 2-3 years ago but the suggestions there don't really provide any help.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-execution-times-for-my-sitecore-scheduled-task

Comment: Thanks Marek but I'm looking for a programmatical way of getting these times and I've updated my question. I'm looking to get date time fo the publish job if it makes sense.

Comment: As I understand your question, you are currently using an `<agent>`. Would you consider creating a Sitecore scheduled task? Then you could see the last run time on the schedule item: http://i.imgur.com/rtWIDkp.png

Comment: The publish task last run date time is what I want to capture. Since this is already OOTB, I don't feel like recreating it.

Comment: @Gabbar in that case, you can use `Database.Properties.GetLastPublishDate(Database target, Language language)`

Comment: Can you add your comment as answer. I'll make it best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.

When Sitecore executes any job, it runs `<job>` pipeline defined in `Sitecore.config` (or `web.config` in older versions). This pipeline has `SignalStart` and `SignalEnd` processors, but the only thing they do is logging the information that job started or finished:

```c#
public static void SignalStart(JobArgs args)
{
  Job job = args.Job;
  job.Status.LogInfo("Job started: {0}", job.Name);
}

public static void SignalEnd(JobArgs args)
{
  Job job = args.Job;
  string str = string.Empty;
  if (job.Status.Processed > 0L)
    str = job.Status.Processed.ToString();
  job.Status.LogInfo("Job ended: {0} (units processed: {1})", job.Name, str);
}
```

You can do what you need manually by analyzing the log files (see https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1234/277 ) or you can add your own custom processors to the pipeline mentioned above and store this information in some other place / database / whatever suits you best.

Comment: Marek .. thanks for the input but Dmytro's property is what I was looking for.